# Wget retrieving images with an absolute URL

Tags: html, wget

How do I use wget to retrieve a single page which has some images with relative URLs and some with absolute URLs?

I have tried

```
wget -E -H -k -K -p --no-check-certificate -cookies=on --load-cookies cookie.txt -e robots=off -H http://example.com/content/page.html
```

Images with relative URLs are downloading, but the absolute ones (e.g. http://example.com/assets/images/img.file") are not downloading.

Comment: This absolute urls comes from single domain, or from multiple domains?

Comment: they are from the same domain as the html page. even though they are from the same domain the images will not download if they use an absolute url

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify the domain using the `--domain=` option in `wget`:

```
wget -E -H -k -K -p --no-check-certificate - -cookies=on --load-cookies cookie.txt -e robots=off --domain=example.com http://example.com/content/page.html
```

Comment: It still won't download the images with absolute url's :(

Comment: It works, however, qzb didn't use the right option syntax, I edited to include `--domain=example.com`

Comment: Thank you, I've thought that this syntax is acceptable.